# A good substitute for bank statement

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I made an earlier post about my situation, and basically I couldn't get a bank statement for my account because it would entail being physically present at my bank in the Philippines, and I couldn't fly there because my flights got cancelled. I'm applying for a U.K. visitor visa from Denmark.

Would it be acceptable to submit a pdf file of the transactions on my bank account that I downloaded from my bank's online service? My bank can issue a bank statement through its mobile banking service but for some reason, it can only do so for current accounts; mine's a savings account. The pdf file could only reflect transactions over 90 days, but it does show my stipend credited though in my local currency instead of in US dollar as noted in my pay slips. Would it suffice to pinpoint in a cover letter the matching account numbers on my pay slips and the pdf file as proof of my financial situation in lieu of the bank statement?

Comment: All of my banks provide PDFs of their official monthly statements, instead of posting them. You should be able to print these.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, not my bank, unfortunately. I tried it earlier but they only provide this service for current accounts.

Comment: Can they mail a statement to you?

Comment: @Daniil, not with the lockdown there. The bank's website says "Due to the General Community Quarantine implemented in Metro Manila, the Contact Center eMail services is temporarily discontinued."

Comment: Do you have historical statements you can use? Do you have consistent income from a job?

Comment: I just got an email when I requested for my bank statement to be emailed, and this is an excerpt: Dear Valued Customer, please be advised that BDO Customer Care Officers no longer accommodate credit card balance and transaction inquiries via email.

              We encourage you to bank safely from home via BDO Online
              Banking or the BDO Mobile Banking App.

Comment: @Daniil, I have a letter of appointment that indicates my stipend and other perks, a financing commitment noted in my Ph.D. plan, and a commitment from my supervisor to increase my stipend over the next six months, which I plan to submit together with the payslips and the transaction file. I'm also waiting for my aunt to provide a bank statement because I'll be staying with her for the duration of my trip.

Answer (score 8):

I got my visa, which means yes, UKVI did accept a printout of transactions over 90 days on my savings account, which I downloaded online, as evidence of financial means. I did mention the reasons why I couldn't provide a bank statement and that I put notes pinpointing my stipend in the local currency and for which month.